Client not receiveing response from Application Gateway timing out and collecting 400 httpStatus
I have a NodeJS Express API.
It exposes an endpoint expecting a multipart form to collect files.
It is deployed in an AKS instance.
The AKS is behind an Application Gateway.
A client is performing several serial calls toward the endpoint described above.
At some point, at POST request N of M, where N < M, it stops receiving an answer, simply timing out.
There's no pattern in the failing requests.
The application gateway logs (AzureDiagnostics table) display a record with dimension 'httpStatus_d' valued 400 and no 'serverStatus_s' dimension.
The API logs display no request, meaning the request is not being forwarded by the application gateway.
I removed the WAF_v2 and redeployed the AGW as a Standard_v2 tier (no waf, so no policies should block the request at this point) and still experiencing the issue.
I made all the experimenting that i could think of, and i came across no solution.
It would be something just to understand what's going on with AGW...

Refer this :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-overview#http-settings to set maxRequestBodySize on your Application Gateway to handle larger file uploads @strongmmc


Client not receiveing response from Application Gateway timing out and collecting 400 httpStatus

In general, this type issues can happen from the client-side configurations as well. Check if your NodeJS API is scaling properly within the AKS cluster.
We can adjust this maxRequestBodySize on your Application Gateway to handle larger files uploads using AzureCLI.
az network application-gateway http-settings update \
      --gateway-name myAppGateway \
      --resource-group myResourceGroup \
      --name appGatewayBackendHttpSettings \
      --max-request-body-size 10485760 # For 10MB

We must make sure client request and timeout and backend timeout settings on the AGW will be helpful in achiveing this.
az network application-gateway http-settings update \
      --gateway-name myAppGateway \
      --resource-group myResourceGroup \
      --name appGatewayBackendHttpSettings \
      --timeout 180 # Increase to 3 minutes, or adjust as needed

Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502?source=recommendations
Client not receiveing response from Application Gateway timing out and collecting 400 httpStatus - Microsoft Q&A answer by Sina Salam
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/monitor-application-gateway-reference#resource-logs

the http-settings doc says nothing regarding a --max-request-body-size parameter. the CLI is returning errors: unrecognized arguments: --max-request-body-size 10485760
